# Rails paperclip gem with Android Retrofit 2.X not working

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, retrofit2

I am creating rails backend to upload image from browser & mobile client(Android) using paperclip gem. It working fine with all web browser,mobile browser and also HTTP REST Client tool, but not working with android client with retrofit http library. Are this compatible with each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The answer is YES**
Is not easy to make it works but,

Here is how i did it... its working for me

Interface Declaration

```
public interface MultimediaApi {

@Multipart
@POST("api/v1/multimedia")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadMultimedia(@Part("tipo]") String tipo,
                               @Part("archivo\"; filename=\"myimageName\" ") RequestBody archivo, // archivo is the how we named the field of the file in rails server
// see filename=\"myimageName\" does not have file extension to avoid problems with paperclip content types validations
                               @Part("texto") String texto,
                               @Part("acoplable_id") String acoplable_id,
                               @Part("acoplable_type") String acoplable_type
                              );
}
```

On Execution thread

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(RestConnection.BASE_URL_MULTIMEDIA)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    MultimediaApi apiService =
            retrofit.create(MultimediaApi.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call;
    MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg");
    File file = new File(filePath);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, file);

    call = apiService.uploadMultimedia(
                        type.toString(),
                        requestBody,
                        text.toString(),
                        acopable_id.toString(),
                        acopable_type.toString()
                );

    Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();


        int statusCode = response.code();
        if (statusCode == 201) {
            // Server response OK            
        } else {
           //failed
                Throwable th = new Throwable("Status Code:" + statusCode + " Error uploading image... Response: " + response.body());
                return th;
            }
```

this examples help me a lot, to resolve my problem, i just made some changes to get it working, so be careful to see each detail

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

```
/**Pura Vida**/
```

Comment: Thanks.. It was helpful.. I was missing filename property for request.